# element click intercepted (click work perfectly)(selenium python)(popup)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, popup, click

I'm trying to automate a website using python selenium.

```
# ----- click on the sign up popup
popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/p/a")
popup.click()
```

click is working fine and the pop-up message is showing perfectly. but after that my I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#mailmunch-pop-940306" class="btn-link btn-auto btn-intro btn-primary">...</a> is not clickable at point (1263, 589). Other element would receive the click: <div class="mailmunch-inner-overlay" id="mailmunch-inner-overlay-178218df563cebd"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)
```

and the code stop working. what can I do?
please help!

Comment: This is a website issue, because it has an overlay over the button which may capture the click. Manually it may work but at time can create bugs on websites. Either you ask devs to fix the overlay or you use javascript to click on that button which will not raise this exception.

Comment: please add sceenshtos and html

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the overlay. Without the HTML I can only offer a couple of solutions:

- Find the dismiss button of the overlay, click it.
- Use Javascript to remove the overlay from the DOM
- Wait until the overlay disappears

Comment: the overlay is a main part i cant get rid of it. the sign up part is in the overlay

Comment: Does the click work fine, or does it give you the error message you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are receiving a described error after you are trying to find an element from that pop-up window? So it's not the line you are thinking that is producing the error. If that is the case, then when you are trying to for example click something in that pop-up window, try the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,""))).click()
```

You need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/p/a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", popup)
```

Try invoking click directly to the element so that it bypasses the overlay or click it's close button.